# selenium IDE without Export Test Case As

Tags: selenium, testing

I want to test a web project. install the chrome extension
but I want to export test case as python code but it seems the extension does not have this option.
Is there any good way to test web project?

Comment: Which chrome extension? For testing javascript you can use 'jest', 'mocha', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use **Katalon Recorder** extension to export code instead of using selenium IDE. Advantage of this extension is allowed user to export code in the different unit test [eg. Nunit,Junit] and also language syntax to export such as Java, C# and so on.

See Details and Download at

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid